# New hard drive not recognized on a Dell Adaptec 2610SA 6 port SATA RAID PCI card

Tags: raid

I have a Dell Adaptec 2610SA 6 port SATA RAID PCI card with 3 hard drives on it and everything works fine.

I plugged another hard drive to it and the system (Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit) seems not to recognize it.

Strange thing is that, as happened in the past, if I re-install the system, it recognizes the new hardware plugged to RAID card.

Of course I don't want to re-install ubuntu each time I plug a new hard drive on my RAID card. Any idea? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the adaptec card is with the hardware RAID BIOS, then you should setup your HDD inside the BIOS (part of current raid, as a new raid, or JBOD). Then it should be visible from any partition manager from current system. Actually do not have spec of this adaptec...